How to make the numbering non-italic in a theorem environment?
A typical theorem in my document looks like

I would like to have the labels (A1) and (A2) non-italic. IMHO, this would be more aesthetic because these label would align with Assumption 1.1.. Thank you so much for your elaboration!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath,enumitem}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{assumption} We assume that 
\begin{enumerate}[label=(A\arabic*)]
\item Statement 1
\item Statement 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{assumption}

\end{document}


Maybe simply label=\normalfont(A\arabic*), but I'm no regular enumitem user.

@campa Thank you so much for your elegant solution!

Use \textnormal{} or \normalfont.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath,enumitem}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{assumption} We assume that 
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textnormal{(A\arabic*)}]
\item Statement 1
\item Statement 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{assumption}

\end{document}


For a global setting, use the following codes.
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textnormal{(A\theenumi)}}%\labelenumi the first level of enumerate.

By the way, for assumptions, it's better use the style of definitions other than that of theorems, i.e., the content of the assumption shouldn't be italic.

Can we make this global for all enumerate environments in a document?

@Akira I add some more comments.

Thank you so much for your suggestion on the style of assumptions!

I have found a global and efficient solution from this answer: \setlist{font=\normalfont}. The full code is
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath,enumitem}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{assumption}[theorem]{Assumption}

\begin{document}

\setlist{font=\normalfont}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{assumption} We assume that 
\begin{enumerate}[label=(A\arabic*)]
\item Statement 1
\item Statement 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{assumption}

\end{document}

